# Reading the content of a txt file and follow conditions with C

Tags: c, file

I'm having an issue with my little program in C , I want to read a file and check the string that's in the 2nd line , and put the chars of the line into a table , but I must follow some conditions

this is what my txt file look like :

> NOMLOT:500
>
> 0001::16:27::47::68:79::3::::43:53::71:81::17:28:31::59:::85

I want to display an array like this
http://i44.tinypic.com/35avekw.jpg

there is my code but I know it's not the good way

```
int main()
{
int x,i;
char buf[TAILLE];
char tab[60];
FILE* fichier = NULL;
fichier = fopen("LSBBZ.txt", "r");
if (fichier != NULL)
{
printf("%s\n", get_line(buf, TAILLE, fichier, 2));
for (i=0 ; i<60 ;i++)
{
    if( buf[i] == ':' )
    {
        i =i+1;
        if (buf[i] ==':')
        {
            tab[i] = 219 ;
        }
        else
            tab[i] = buf[i];
    }
    else
        tab[i] = buf[i];
}
}
printf("\n");
}

char *get_line(char *buf, int n, FILE *f, int line)
{
int i;
for (i=0 ;i<line;i++)
{
    if(fgets(buf,n,f) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1 ] = '\0';
}
return buf;
}
```

if you can suggest any method or help me out !
thanks

Comment: Do you want feedback your code?  If so, [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a more appropriate site for your question.

Comment: no I want another way , or any idea about it

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing now?

Comment: use `strsep` for tokenize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example of using `strsep`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if 1
#include <string.h>

//Not required if already exists.
char * strsep(char **sp, const char *sep)
{
    char *p, *s;
    if (sp == NULL || *sp == NULL || **sp == '\0') return(NULL);
    s = *sp;
    p = s + strcspn(s, sep);
    if (*p != '\0') *p++ = '\0';
    *sp = p;
    return(s);
}
#endif

#define Nothing 219

int main(){
    int data[3][9] = {0};
    char input[] = "0001::16:27::47::68:79::3::::43:53::71:81::17:28:31::59:::85";
    char *token, *sp = input;
    int *ip = &data[0][0];
    token=strsep(&sp, ":");////first drop
    while(NULL != (token=strsep(&sp, ":"))){
        *ip++ = (*token != '\0') ? atoi(token) : Nothing ;//Nothing is 219 
    }
    int r, c;
    for(r=0;r<3;++r){
        printf("|");
        for(c=0;c<9;++c){
            int value = data[r][c];
            if(value != Nothing)
                printf("%2d", data[r][c]);
            else
                printf("%2s", "");
            printf("|");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

/* result
|  |16|27|  |47|  |68|79|  |
| 3|  |  |  |43|53|  |71|81|
|  |17|28|31|  |59|  |  |85|
*/
```

Comment: Thank You , I think that will resolve my probleme , I will try with your methode , btw well done @BLUEPIXY